# Can I connect my Java console application with GUI application?

Tags: java, user-interface, console

I have Java console application but I need to create a user interface for the user interaction.

Is it possible to connect the GUI with Java console?

Comment: Note that the Command Line Interface (CLI - 'Command Prompt' on Windows) that launches a Java app. is distinct from the 'Java console' that might appear for a JWS app. or applet.  Like Peter, I find your question rather confusing.  As an aside, you will get more respect and time if you take efforts to use the right 'upper case' in your post.  See my edits for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is however,

You can use the console if you start with java.exe whether you use a GUI or not.  If you use a GUI it is common practice to use javaw.exe which doesn't have a console, but you don't have to start your application that way.

On Unix there is only `java` ;)

You can connect `jconsole` ?Java Console? to either of these.

Answer (score 0):

> I have Java console application but I need to create a user interface for the user interaction.

If I understand you correctly, you have an application that takes input from the command line and you now need a GUI on top of it?

I'd say the easiest way to do this should be to create a new GUI app and use the exisiting application as a library. You might be able to call the console application's `main` method from the UI app and replace the standard input and output streams with your own implementations that connect to the GUI.